# Ubuntu 21.04 boot issues on MSI Prestige EVO 14

Tags: boot, display

I wanted to install 21.04 on my laptop, an MSI Prestige 14 EVO but unfortunately the operating system does not boot. GRUB appears and, either selecting normal boot or boot in with "safe graphics", the flick screen will appear as if there is a disturbed transmission and after a few seconds it will reboot and return to GRUB. The USB stick works correctly because tried on another computer starts it without problems. Has anyone had the same problem or have any ideas? Thank you all.

To be clear about the issue, it is the same of this user at this link:
https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1302114-ubuntu-gnome-corrupted-screen-at-boothelp/

Even in this case, the hardware is MSI.

Comment: As usual, update UEFI before anything else. Then assure you're booting in UEFI mode. If the symptom persists try booting with `nomodeset` although from what Google says this model has no dGPU so this shouldn't be needed.

Comment: Report the bug https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en

Comment: Hi, UEFI is updated and the nomodeset option does not work. The issue is still present. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Today MSI released a new bios and it solves the issue.